# Where can I find a database of all recorded 姓?

Tags: characters, names, surnames, database

I can't read or write Chinese well, so this question is perhaps easy to search for if you do. So far I have had no luck.

I am looking for a list of all recorded Chinese last names (or at least the majority of them). Most lists I have found online only have the most common few hundred but I really want to have the whole of it and that doesn't seem to be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few dictionaries that collect surnames. The links show you the book cover and metadata.

中国姓氏大辞典 (Dictionary of Chinese Surnames, https://book.douban.com/subject/4286239/)

中国姓氏源流大辞典 (Etymological Dictionary of Chinese Surnames, https://book.douban.com/subject/25870389/)